# Strange optimization of initialization

Tags: c++, c, volatile

I realize that my example not correct in general. But interesting to find out how it works.

```
/* C/C++ (gcc-4.3.4) */
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {

        /*volatile*/ int i = 5;
        int j = 500;

        int *p = &j;

        printf( "%d %x\n", *p, p );

        p++;

        printf( "%d %x\n", *p, p  ); // works correct with volatile (*p is 5)
        //printf( "%d %x\n", *p, &i  ); //  works correct without volatile

        return 0;
}
```

Is it some kind of optimization?

**UPDT** 
Ok i got about UB. I won't hope on another else.

BUT if i have 2 int vars which placed adjacent to each others (see addresses) why this code shouldn't works?

Comment: It would help a lot of you were to describe what you're seeing, and (if it's different) what you expect to see. Right now, the short answer is that your code simply has undefined behavior, so anything could happen. Not quite sure what you're trying to get at about `volatile` though.

Comment: After `p++;` you're into the realm of Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Is `i` defined as `volatile` in your actual code in either case?

Comment: @JerryCoffin http://ideone.com/CPYl7

Comment: It reminds me of a time when I was writing a c application, and I didn't initialize enough of a character array, but when I printed it out, the garbage looked like something.

Comment: @SamIam but i have initialized memory here - review variable addresses.

Comment: @triclosan: what makes you think that `i` needs to be in memory ? It can just as easily be in a register or even be optimised away completely.

Comment: be so kind to specify reason of downvote

Answer (score 5):

```
p++;
```

The code has undefined behavior. Pointer is pointing to some garbage location. Dereferencing it leads to unpredicted results.

Comment: I realize it. But with `volatile` or with explicit using of `&i` i got constant result. Interesting explanation of it

Comment: Unfortunately, expected behavior is part of unexpected behavior :)

Comment: @triclosan seems like you don't understand what undefined behaviour means: it means there's no point in reasoning about it. It doesn't mean anything else.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes  Maybe instead of being condecending like that you can try to explain what it means,

Comment: @SamIam I already explained it. That's what it means: nothing reasonable.

Comment: Well, it worth noting that `p++` is perfectly legal. No undefined behavior here. Dereferencing `p` leads to UB, not `++` itself.

Comment: @Mahesh: p++ is defined by 6.5.5 7 of the 1999 C standard. A pointer to a single object acts, for purposes of arithmetic operators, like a pointer to the first element of an array of size one, and pointers may be incremented to one element beyond the last element of the array, which is what this p++ does. Dereferencing the new value does indeed have undefined behavior.

Comment: @EricPostpischil There is nothing wrong with the pointer arithmetic as noted by AndreyT. Dereferencing it is what causes UB.

Answer (score 0):

What do you call `corerct`?
It isn't guaranted, how variables will be stored, so `ANY` result is correct

Answer (score 0):

Both variables are not necessarly adjacent in memory. You could use an array to do this.

```
#define PRINT(p) (printf("%i %p\n", *(p), (void *)(p)))

int t[2];
int *a = &t[0];
int *b = &t[1];

*a = 5;
*b = 6;

int *p = a;
PRINT(p);

++p;
PRINT(p);
```

Comment: I know what is not necessary. But i see it from the out. And have reasons to expect this because it's stack variables

Comment: It's possible, but padding bits can be added for alignment. Then your assumption is wrong... It's a very bad practice.